# Why I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in my linked list?

Tags: c++

I'm just learning C++ right now, so I wanted to create a simple linked list program to learn how to write C++. (I come from Java and Python). Sometimes (not every time) I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class LinkedList
{

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *next;
};


private:
    Node *head;
public:

LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

void addNode(int value, int index)
{
    Node *node = new Node;
    node->value = value;
    Node *n = head;
    if (index == 0)
    {
        node->next = n;
        head = node;
        return;
    }

    int size = getSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == index - 1)
        {
            node->next = n->next;
            n->next = node;
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void addNode(int value)
{
    Node *node = new Node;
    node->value = value;
    if (!head)
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        head = node;
        return;
    }
    Node *n = head;
    int size = getSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        n = n->next;
    }
    n->next = node;
}

int getSize()
{
    Node *_node = new Node;
    _node->value = head->value;
    _node->next = head->next;
    int size = 1;
    while (_node != NULL)
    {
        _node = _node->next;
        size++;
    }
    return size - 1;
}

string printList()
{
    Node *n = head;
    string output = to_string(n->value);
    int size = getSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        n = n->next;
        output.append(" -> " + to_string(n->value));
    }
    return output;
}
};
```

I get this error in the method "getSize()" on the line "_node = _node->next;" I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside  `addNode` you are not initializing the `next` pointer of `Node` to `NULL` when there is a head node.

You must initialize it to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works